# Error 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 474 not upgraded

Tags: ubuntu, installation, updates

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 , and kernel 3.16.0-30 , if i do :

```
sudo apt-get update     
sudo apt-get install libtool automake libncurses5-dev kernel-package
```

or

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cvs subversion build-essential git-core g++-multilib gcc-multilib
```

the result is  :

```
ore g++-multilib gcc-multilib
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... 50%
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version.
cvs is already the newest version.
g++-multilib is already the newest version.
gcc-multilib is already the newest version.
git-core is already the newest version.
subversion is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 474 not upgraded.
```

what is the problem ? and how resolved this problem ?

Comment: There is no problem. Read the actual words of the results, where every single line says **is already the newest version**. That means nothing needed to be upgraded, installed, or removed. It says it in very clear, plain language. Text output from doing things almost always contains information that is meaningful; otherwise, they wouldn't bother putting the text there in the first place.

Comment: Is it  I have? Or must be installed

Comment: It says you already have the latest version, as I said previously.  Nothing needs to be upgraded, installed or removed**, because **you already have the newest version**. You have. You do not need to install. There is no error.

Answer (score 4):

This usually happens when some of the packages are kept back. You can use the following commands (which worked for me)

Install aptitude
`sudo apt install aptitude`

Then, run this command
`sudo aptitude safe-upgrade`

Comment: this the only way working
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

this works for me

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Answer (score 2):

The `source.list` might be outdated. Try replacing your `/etc/apt/sources.list` with the following `source.list`

for [ubuntu 14.04](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/justbuchanan/d045498c95fa1cd2dc70/raw/789264b08c87c3ae8d836c91887f57d7d6496851/sources.list)
for [ubuntu 16.04](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rohitrawat/60a04e6ebe4a9ec1203eac3a11d4afc1/raw/fcdfde2ab57e455ba9b37077abf85a81c504a4a9/sources.list)
for [ubuntu 18.04](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rhuancarlos/c4d3c0cf4550db5326dca8edf1e76800/raw/480bc68edae51e704114b0f4e256f543f25961af/sources.list)
for [ubuntu 20.04](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ishad0w/788555191c7037e249a439542c53e170/raw/3822ba49241e6fd851ca1c1cbcc4d7e87382f484/sources.list)

After replacing source list do following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

1. create a bash file (upgrade.sh) in your home directory.
2. paste this code in it.

.

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get install aptitude -y

sudo aptitude safe-upgrade

sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

3.save it

4.run : `bash upgrade.sh`

5. everytime just don't type these commands just enter (bash upgrade.sh)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
Some background info:
I am running ubuntu server 22.0 LTS in virtualbox & accessing using SSH. But the commands should work on practically any installation of ubuntu as long as you can use apt command.

**Step 1:**

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade && sudo apt autoremove
```

**This won't resolve your problem** but make it easier for you (lazy people :)), to run the following commands.

Output of the above command:

```
Hit:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Hit:4 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu jammy-apps-security InRelease
Hit:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Hit:6 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu jammy-apps-updates InRelease
Hit:7 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu jammy-infra-security InRelease
Hit:8 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu jammy-infra-updates InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
8 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libnss-systemd libpam-systemd libsystemd0 libudev1 systemd systemd-sysv systemd-timesyncd udev
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
```

**Step 2:**

Copy the 2nd last line, which contains a list of packages (in space separated format), that were not upgraded by previous commands. **This will help you to NOT type the entire list if there are hundreds of'em.**

We have **3 solutions** for this problem, **try them 1 by 1**. depending upon the configuration, preferences, and the reason for the packages not getting upgraded, any 1 of these can resolve the problem. **For me, the 3rd solution worked.**

**Solution 1:** (didn't work for me, but has been reported to work for many users)

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

**Solution 2:** (didn't work for me, but has been reported to work for many users)

```
sudo apt upgrade --with-new-pkgs
```

**Solution 3:** (worked on my machine)

```
sudo apt install --only-upgrade libnss-systemd libpam-systemd libsystemd0 libudev1 systemd systemd-sysv systemd-timesyncd udev
```

In the above command, you can ***replace the package list with your own list that you copied in step 2 above***.

Try all 3 solutions, because depending upon the configuration, preferences, and the reason for the packages not getting upgraded, any 1 of these can resolve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get install aptitude -y

sudo aptitude safe-upgrade

sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: Avoid code only answer and provide an explanation.